# API for creating eth wallet

Tags: ether, wallets

I've been looking for an api similar to bloopi (not local), which gives you ability to quickly and easily create a wallet. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @smarx, do you have the source code for your api example https://wt-e79da0981ef1f312f9ba7d4331653992-0.run.webtask.io/generate-ethereum-account I can view?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19762)

Comment: I have same problem i want to create etherum wallet address and i want address and private key but i am unable to generate both so can you please suggest some apis so i can create etherum wallet address for my platform.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19788)

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to use an API to create a wallet (generate an address), because then you would have to trust the security of the API provider. People generally use local software (even if it's in the browser) to do this. E.g. `geth`, `Parity`, `Jaxx`, `MetaMask`, `MyEtherWallet`.

If you've already explored those options and they don't meet your needs, please provide more details about what you're looking for.

Comment: I do not care about security. Your answer does not match my question. I need an external api, not local

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're asking for. I'm just explaining why it's unlikely to exist. May I ask why you don't care about security? What's your use case?

Comment: I made an API, just in case you really don't care about security: https://wt-e79da0981ef1f312f9ba7d4331653992-0.run.webtask.io/generate-ethereum-account. (Of course, I recommend strongly against anyone using that.)

Comment: My client asked to do it this way

Comment: Is this possible or not? If it's for a PoC concept pet project, and you would like to experiment with the network, you have the luxury of not worrying about security. If there's actually money involved - then you should worry.

Comment: Of course it's possible; I provided a link that does it. But I don't understand why people are trying to make HTTP requests to get a private key when you can just generate one locally.